# The dimensions of the output in the documentclass "cd" are completely wrong

Tags: covers

I'm trying to make cd covers using the document class [`cd`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cd).

I've been able to use it fairly well, and I was hopeful to get a nice output. However, I was extremely disappointed to see my document once it was printed and I was cutting it out: it just seems like "the square" (i.e., the box that is formed by the eight small lines - see the image I added below) is not of the appropriate size, it's too small in a very significant way. And yes, I'm using a regular compact disc cd box so it's not just about me. The attached picture is the *back* of the cover, but the front cover is too small as well.

This is ridiculous: this class is, as it is now, completely useless since it is unusable! So it needs to be corrected.

I've tried to look at the code of the document class `cd`, but I can't quite understand it well enough to be able to make the appropriate fix; however, I think that for someone more perspicacious than me (certainly the person(s) who created this class), it wouldn't be too hard to correct it.

So, who can fix this?

[image: Back of the CD]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you sure you printed the document with all page-scaling features of your printer driver disabled? Often times the default setting is "fit to printable area" or similar, which can wreak havoc with sensitive dimensions.

Comment: Hi and welcome, i think a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) is in order to rule out any coding mistakes. After all, you are not the first person to use the package and if anybody would have seen something strange, they would have reported it.

Comment: Too small by how much?  (Try adding `\usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage[grid, gridunit=mm, gridcolor=red!20, subgridcolor=blue!20]{eso-pic}` to get a ruled background grid.)  It looks like "the square" is about 120mm x 120mm.  Is that wrong?

Comment: Problem solved: it turns out my problem was, as suggested, indeed caused by default settings of my printer regarding page-scaling features. It was foolish of me not to be able to come up with this myself. May it be a warning to others. Jon's comment was very helpful too. Thanks everyone for your help! The conclusion is that the document class "cd" works perfectly fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue as the printing/PDF viewer end rather than with TeX.